# Trouble making contents of two separate folders (on separate local drives) appear as one folder

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, mirroring

I would like the contents (files NOT folders) of two folders on different (local) drives to appear as one.  Preferably I would like it to be indistinguishable as to where the actual file path is and editing, renaming, deleting the file will be reflected in its actual location.  What they must do is A) cannot take up space on both drives and B) Appear on search bar in that folder

I've messed with Link Shell and as far as I can tell it's not possible this way.

1. Create symlink on files & drop to other location - This is the only method that kind of works, but the extension is changed to .symlink which is annoying and the deal breaker is the files don't show up when searching.
2. Create hardlink on files - Copies files over taking up space on both drives
3. Link one folder & drop as symlink, clone or mirror and paste contents of the other in it = takes up space on both drives

Some of these methods would work if they were on the same drive but don't in this situation.

Any other things I could try?

Comment: `but the extension is changed to .symlink` .. no, not with a real symlink and I don't see this behavior with the [hard link shell extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html).  I just tested it.  I get a file that shows the shortcut icon but otherwise looks and acts like the real thing.  I can also look at a file from WSL and it too shows as legit from Linux.  If you look at "type" under properties->details in the file in explorer, it shows ".symlink" but this IS NOT the actual extension.  Do a dir on it and you will see.

Comment: You can't even make a hardlink across different hard drives is the problem with that.

Comment: No, that is EXACTLY what I tested.  Link from a file on my D:\ drive to my desktop on C:\.  Works just fine.  If I mouse over the link, it shows "type .symlink" but the extension is still correct.

Comment: From Linux, this is what my link looks like `/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/eduke32_win64.7z -> /mnt/d/Games/eduke32_win64.7z` . The reason I show from linux is the path is more descriptive.  Perhaps it is how you are creating the link.  I right drag the file and choose "Create Symbolic Link Here".  `MKLINK` also works for me from the command line.

Comment: True - if you drop on desktop it looks that way but in a folder if you sort by file type they'll show up as .symlink.  Not being able to search folder contents makes it a moot point for me though, unless there's a way to tell windows to allow shortcuts to show up in results